# How To upload file from React Native to ASP.NET Core WebAPI

Tags: react-native, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

I want to upload an image file from react native to my server

React native code:

```
uploadData = () => {
let formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('PhotoFile', {
    uri: this.state.image,
    type: 'image/png',
    name: 'photo'
  });
formdata.append('Title', this.state.title);

fetch('https://link/api/memes',{
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
  body: formdata
  }).then(response => {
    alert(response.status);
  }).catch(err => {
    alert(err);
  });  
}
```

I am using expo-image-picker to pick an image, and i store it in state

My Controller has a following prototype:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateTitle([FromForm] TitleCreateDto titleCreateDto)
```

TitleCreateDto class lookes like this:

```
 public class TitleCreateDto
{
    public TitleCreateDto()
    {
        DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public IFormFile PhotoFile { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63570616/uploading-blob-file-in-react-native-contents-is-empty/63571279#63571279)

Comment: `this.state.image` what's data you assigned to it? Is it Base64-encoded string or local path to image? Besides, you define **PhotoFile** property as **IFormFile** in your model class but you provide PhotoFile with json object in formdata.